# found 79 moderate severity vulnerabilities run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I am unable to create a react app. I am getting this error when I was trying to run "npx create-react-app". It created all the node modules[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDowl.png)  and struck with this error. Please suggest to me any solution.

```
found 79 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Please post text instead of links to images of text.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same Issue. `npm audit` showed me it had todo with a postcss ReDoS-Vulnerability.

For a workaround, you should check out [postcss 7.0.0 - 8.2.9 Severity: moderate Regular Expression Denial of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501746/postcss-7-0-0-8-2-9-severity-moderate-regular-expression-denial-of-service)

You should run `npm audit` inside your project folder and confirm that all the vulnerabilities are from postcss. If you're just learning reactJS, you can ignore these vulnerabilitys. But if you want to deploy your project, use the workaround.