# postcss 7.0.0 - 8.2.9 Severity: moderate Regular Expression Denial of Service

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, postcss, react-scripts

When creating a new project under `create-react-app`, you get warnings straight away regarding a vulnerability found in `postcss`.

Issue reported by npm: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1693

Related open issues can be found here:

- https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1574
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10945

The issue has been patched on `postcss v8.2.10`, but it's still present when creating new projects as `react-scripts` hasn't upgraded the dependency yet.

So, my problem here is I can no longer run builds as they fail due to the vulnerability.

Since I can't wait for them to get it patched before to keep working on my stuff (they seem to be aware of it since a year ago), is there some workaround that could be applied to solve it?

I tried adding a `postcss` resolution on `package.json`:

```js
  "resolutions": {
    "postcss": "^8.2.10"
  },
```

but that didn't land me far.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Doing a npm audit fix --force downgrades react-scripts  resolving theses vulnerabilities but introducing yet more moderate and high vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This article helped me.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions.
To use resolutions you wrote you should force them by adding this script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

after that run `npm install` and it should overwrite all nested dependencies

Anyway it will not work due many dependencies. Good news is that support for postcss 8 is already merged and probably will be released soon https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9664

Comment: By deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and following your suggestion, I managed to get it working with no vulnerabilities - only problem in forcing this resolution is you get an error when running `npm audit fix` due to the package tree being invalid - I guess we'll have to wait the patch, but at least this does temporarily, so thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `yarn` which works with the `resolutions` in the `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

Switching to `Yarn` makes this far simpler.

```sh
rm -rf ./node_modules 
rm ./package-lock.json
```

edit your `package.json` :
<sub>add any other package versions to upgrade from `npm / yarn audit` here also</sub>

```json
  "resolutions": 
  {
    "postcss": "^8.2.10"
  },
```

`yarn install` then running `yarn audit` should yield the magic words:

```
0 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 999
✨  Done in 1.10s.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reduce the audit issues down to one moderate vulnerability due to the `browserslist` package in my post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68046680/1669123

Updating `postcss` to version 8.x.x in resolutions results in build issues for me. I'm a web dev newcomer and guessing version 8 breaking changes for plugins is the culprit. Version 7.0.36 is the latest version 7 `postcss` that builds and runs for me. The changelog states that this version has the ReDoS fix backported from version 8. I can't seem to solve the `browserslist` package issue without it causing 'module not found' errors at runtime. I'm guessing we'll have to wait on the CRA team to update `react-scripts` for a more thorough solution.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, you can solve it using yarn audit instead of npm.

```
yarn audit --groups postcss
```

This command will only ignore postcss package from the security check.