# how to solve postcss vulnerabilities in app create with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I create a new app using create-react-app 1 month ago and recently I got this message from `npm update`:

```
80 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

`npm audit` gives me:

```
postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.8, which is a breaking change
```

I try `npm audit fix` but nothing changes and `npm audit fix --force` install an older version of react-script (current 4.0.3 to 2.1.8) so it doesn't seem like a good solution.

`npm install postcss@latest --save` and `npm install postcss@8.2.15 --save` doesn't change anything either.

What is the best way to fix this vulnerability?

Comment: are you use postcss for using sass ?

Comment: I don't use postcss or sass, it's a dependency of react-scripts

Comment: Ok i think i found see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501746/postcss-7-0-0-8-2-9-severity-moderate-regular-expression-denial-of-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502823/8499653

the support for postcss 8 is already merged and probably will be released soon

you can use the npm package `npm-force-resolutions` to temporarily fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I lost half a day to this, all the NPM based solutions & packages didn't work. force-resolutions wasn't working for me.

Switching to `Yarn` makes this far simpler.

```sh
rm -rf ./node_modules 
rm ./package-lock.json
```

edit your `package.json` :
<sub>add any other package versions to upgrade from `npm / yarn audit` here also</sub>

```json
  "resolutions": 
  {
    "postcss": "^8.2.10"
  },
```

`yarn install` then running `yarn audit` should yield the magic words:

```
0 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 999
✨  Done in 1.10s.
```