# wan i create new react App using npx create-react-app App_Name Its Show This Error (found 8 vulnerabilities)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

wan I create a new app in react
Command For Create App **npx create-react-app**
Its Shows This error
found 8 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 4 high) in 2166 scanned packages
8 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
I'm using the latest version of node.js
I run Comment "**npm audit fix**" Or "**npm audit fix --force**" But it Not Fix my error
Here is All error
Command "**NPM Audit**"

```
 Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         postcss

  Patched in      >=7.0.36 <8.0.0 || >=8.2.10

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > postcss

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         browserslist

  Patched in      >=4.16.5

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > react-dev-utils > browserslist

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747


  Moderate        Regular expression denial of service

  Package         glob-parent

  Patched in      >=5.1.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 >
                  chokidar > glob-parent

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751


  Moderate        Regular expression denial of service

  Package         glob-parent

  Patched in      >=5.1.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > glob-parent

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751


  High            Denial of Service

  Package         css-what

  Patched in      >=5.0.1

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo >
                  css-select > css-what

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754


  High            Denial of Service

  Package         css-what

  Patched in      >=5.0.1

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano
                  > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select
                  > css-what

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         normalize-url

  Patched in      >=4.5.1 <5.0.0 || >=5.3.1 <6.0.0 || >=6.0.1

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > mini-css-extract-plugin > normalize-url

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         normalize-url

  Patched in      >=4.5.1 <5.0.0 || >=5.3.1 <6.0.0 || >=6.0.1

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano
                  > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-normalize-url >
                  normalize-url

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755

found 8 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 4 high) in 2166 scanned packages
  8 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

How Can I fix this error.

Comment: You can just stand on them unless you've got faced any errors. Ignore them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time I will ignore them and continues my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the question I posted couple of weeks ago here [postcss 7.0.0 - 8.2.9 Severity: moderate Regular Expression Denial of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501746/postcss-7-0-0-8-2-9-severity-moderate-regular-expression-denial-of-service).

Short answer is there is no patch yet so you should wait or, if you can't afford that, then you will need to use `yarn` as explained in one of the answers.